# DKIM - OpenSSL error: data too large for key size

Tags: centos, email, exim, dkim, opendkim

I have installed **openDKIM** on a **CentOS** server running **Exim** as my MTA. I have gone through the configuration and tested the keys and eveything seems fine.

I have created the public and private keys, added the DNS TXT entry and setup the KeyTable, SigningTable and TrustedHosts. I have also setup the `opendkim.conf`.

But when I send a mail and use some testing tools like DKIMValidator.com to check the results, I get the error

```
OpenSSL error: data too large for key size
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong. I have scanned through the Internet looking for help but havent found any.

Would appreciate if anyone can help.

Edit:

I have added the test result from [dkimvalidator](http://dkimvalidator.com) below. From the test, you can see how exim sends the data and header. I dont kow why exim breaks the key with those line breaks. I didnt edit the generated private key. I have a feeling that might be the reason for the failure. Or maybe something else. Would appreciate if anyone can figure it out:

**Test from GMail:**

> DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>           d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
>           h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
>           bh=lifSWpvlWkPq6fMhfFkb4eqAqh4c/ik5j2MtPtLKdUQ=;
>           b=KAR6yadY27q/HPp9WAwU9CBR5DWByyuGIjt4z7VjufvcoeQosSUkAN2mFbuyl56oQZ
>            ey7DXu8dLLEZt8piarfdxZd+NKOb6I+0T4VdFhH7Qne/274f76k0Bmorejpvo/YY4qhP
>            AzULROQszd3usx7cdZZY850I0b9BJ64WHG2AWJGuWXq8XGqhR4O1hmsdMyysooBEGhtK
>            IiMwdQP5tMqk+kMqVREy0KsyExXj3XqN+pi/dfgNaQ3wGv6jC6s4IYcGjSsZ7+Rlf7Lq
>            QzU3HQRtOEzhV5mVqc0wMQDBkdd33oqEp4tM1klN/iuR8YympALvTQplVZo3wSgH316t
>            9/Dw==

**Test From My Server:**

> DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>       d=mydomain.com; s=default; h=Message-ID:Subject:To:From:Date:
>       Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-Version:Sender:Reply-To:Cc:
>       Content-ID:Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:
>       Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:
>       List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;
>        bh=Rd+JR+hUluBNEkJb3S41AuIaal72ZB3FF0ZK1OG0inU=; b=ZZMDQEK35K8JqZVqeoY+3AB9Z
>       fbsOfeuWUD7nXL7nUAS1DGU0GOMO1mVHLyxvujuyPyXEP/YppNW7GowrFc3V/yqum+GcbEG66zJYw
>       MlQa8OFZeKv4250ku3EJ0lXOkpN9mcLGVNia+/GtDWnfVAlFDhzVgwmhbfR1711qro/ECEFe6jq4o
>       Fe6FLzBbelwIFKHL1iQJC3hCHWxYcnWDjXII6ICXfHHejQ61YUtdewxhw6LyPt2RmXa1xVCsY0ZbD
>       DE14Q5FbAimvbaCiWvmK6avSFph/N/+bKSzFLMemm99oOfsTmuHvXJlZv8Jnqmg9rQO8rekpdeDpl
>       BM3j70czg==;

Comment: The key size for your public key is too small to encrypt the data its being used for. What key size did you initially use when generating these keys? I'd say try a larger key length.

Comment: opendkim user 1024 bits by default. I  didnt change it

Comment: Hmm, and what's the length in bytes of your resulting TXT record? Depending on the DNS system being used, some only allow a length of 256 bytes, or 512 bytes (BIND allows 512). However, the base64'd string of your RSA public key should fit within 512 bytes if the key size is below 2,700 bits...

Comment: I have edited the question with more information

Comment: @EdwinOkugbo did you ever determine the issue?